# Converting to lambda and unexpected results

Tags: c#, string, linq, lambda, graph

So, I got the "Type1" code working and it's working fine.  My question is why doesn't "Type2" work?  I thought they were, in essence, doing the same thing but obviously "Type2" isn't doing what I expected it to build the JSON string for a google chart.

```
StringBuilder pieData = new StringBuilder();    

//Type2 - Empty string ""
pieData.Clear();
data.Select(point => pieData.Append($@"['{point.Category}', {point.Count}],"));
pieData.ToString().Dump("JSON");


//Type1 - works fine "['F-01', 10],['A-01', 8],"
foreach (PieDatapoint point in data)
{
    pieData.Append($@"['{point.Category}', {point.Count}],");
}
pieData.ToString().Dump("JSON");
```

Comment: Don't post images of code. Press "edit" and paste the formatted code in the question, mark it an hit the `{}`.

Answer (score 1):

`Select` is a deferred operation. By simply calling `Select` you're not executing it. You must also include a `.ToArray()` or `.ToList()` or execute it using a `foreach` loop.

Had you executed this:

```
data.Select(point => pieData.Append($@"['{point.Category}', {point.Count}],")).ToArray();
```

Or this:

```
foreach (var x in data.Select(point => pieData.Append($@"['{point.Category}', {point.Count}],")))
{ }
```

Then the code would have worked.

Please keep in mind that this only works because `pieData.Append(...)` returns a value. If it didn't then neither approach would even compile.

Answer (score 0):

You csn use ForEach instead of Select for target response if data is List or Array:

```
data.ForEach(point => pieData.Append($@"['{point.Category}', {point.Count}],"));
```

Or by Select and Join:

```
var strings = data.Select(point => $@"['{point.Category}', {point.Count}]").ToList();

string pieData = string.Join(",", strings);
```

Comment: You have no idea if `ForEach` is available on `data`. And what does "target response" mean?

Comment: @Enigmativity, Select & ForEach both is in System Linq namespace

Comment: No, `ForEach` is not. It's a method on `List<T>` and `Array`, but it's not in LINQ.

Comment: @Enigmativity, Yes that's right, Thanks, I add other solution to answer

Comment: But the first answer is invalid. Unless you know it's a `List<>`, but we don't.

Comment: Sorry, you misunderstood about the `Array` usage of `ForEach` - it's not an instance method, it's a `static` method. It needs to be called as `Array.ForEach(data, point => pieData.Append($@"['{point.Category}', {point.Count}],"));`